# Analyzing two algorithms and their times

Tags: algorithm

I have a problem and I would like to know your point of view.

I have two algorithms (algorithm A and algorithm B) and the two algorithms solve the same problem but their elementary operations are different. Both algorithms belong to functions of the same order.

What could be said about the time it takes to run the programs of each algorithm A and B?

Thank you friends.

Comment: What are your two algorithms?

Comment: @kaya3 In theory, they just tell me that, they don't provide me with any algorithm ... I don't know if maybe imagine two algorithms ... :/

Comment: But your question says you have two algorithms. If that is not true then please edit your question to say what your actual problem is. Please also see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: @kaya3 I understand what you tell me, but they asked me this question and I didn't understand this either. That is, they are telling me to imagine two algorithms. I give an example, you have to solve an apple problem, they tell you you have an apple and you have another apple, how many apples do you have? For this you do not need to know if the first apple is green or red ... I explain?

Answer (score 1):

Two or more algorithms can resolve the same problem, the main difference is the execution time, for example: there are more sorting algorithms, but the select sort orders in O (n ^ 2), while the merge sort in O (n log n).